# html button (onlick) not working when sending data to mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I have a forms on a html page which retrieve data from a mysql table. The user can modify these data, or delete the entire row. I have a html button with functionality of deleting the entire row, and with that button I have a javascript function that displays a confirm pop up box confirming if the user wants to delete it. If they click yes then it is sent to another php page where the deletion is performed. The problem is when I click on the confirm box nothing happens, it just stays on the same page. Here is my html and javascript code:

```
<form class="form-inline" method=GET action="envoieModifierAlbumAdmin.php">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="verif()">Supprimer Cet Album</button>
            </td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="exampleInputName2">id: </label>
                <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo "$donnees[id]"?>" id="exampleInputName2" name="id">
            </td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="exampleInputName2">Nom d'album: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" name="titre" value="<?php echo "$donnees[titre]"?>"></td>
            <td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script>
    function verif(){
        var x;
        if(confirm("Vous êtes sûr que vous voulez supprimer ce compte?") == true){
            document.location="supprimerAlbumAdmin.php?id=$_GET['id']";
        }
        else
    }
</script>
```

The only problem is with the button, the other parts of the table above are just to show an example of what the user is modifying. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with onClick instead of onclick and remove else in your function or add else braces like else{}

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh doesn't work either. Could it be something to do with the fact that it's a .php file with javascript inside?

Comment: Open your console and check whats exact error ... u can write js in php its not problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your value should be like this

```
value="<?php echo  $_GET['id'] ?>"
```

not like this

```
value="<?php echo "$donnees[id]"?>"
```

and change button type into **submit**

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


function verif(){
 alert("hi");
        var x;
        if(confirm("Vous êtes sûr que vous voulez supprimer ce compte?") == true){
            
   //window.location.replace("https://google.com");
   //exit();
          return true;
          
        }
        else
          {
            
            return false;
            
            }
        
    }
</script>
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="envoieModifierAlbumAdmin.php">
    <table class="table table-striped">


        <tr>
            <td><label for="exampleInputName2">id: </label>
                <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="exampleInputName2" name="id">
            </td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="exampleInputName2">Nom d'album: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" name="titre" value=""></td>
            <td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="verif()">Supprimer Cet Album</button>
            </td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: $GET needs an underscore $_GET

Comment: `$_GET` is a superglobal http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and this answer needs to be edited for future readers who may think your answer is correct, which it isn't. You still didn't fix the syntax error. Edit: You did fix it, *great*.

Comment: @jothi You're welcome and equally "thank you" ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function verif(){
        var x;
        if(confirm("Vous êtes sûr que vous voulez supprimer ce compte?") == true){
            window.location.href="supprimerAlbumAdmin.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
        }
        else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
function verif(){
    var x;
    if(confirm("Vous êtes sûr que vous voulez supprimer ce compte?")){
        window.location.href="supprimerAlbumAdmin.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work either! Could it be something to do with the fact that it's a .php file with javascript inside?

Comment: I have tried running through jsfiddle. It is working perfectly fine. On "ok" click, it redirects the user to other page